# Is $Iso(V)$ a deformation retract of $GL(V)$ when $V$ is a finite dimensional linear normed space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fa.functional-analysis

Assume that $V$  is  a  finite  dimensional real or complex  normed linear space. Let  $Iso(V)\subset GL(V)\subset L(V)$ be the space of linear isometric endomorphisms, invertible  endomorphism and linear endomorphisms on $V$, respectively. These space have their natural and unique topologies arising from the operator norm on $L(V)$.

> Is $Iso(V)$  a  deformation retract of $GL(V)$?

Comment: For a generic real normed space $Iso(V)$ is trivial, isn't it?

Comment: The answer to the question is yes iff the norm is Euclidean up to a linear automorphism.

Comment: @aglearner  what is  an argument?

Comment: @YCor  may you  give  a  reference  or  an sketch of proof?

Comment: Write $K=\mathrm{Iso}(V)$ and $L$ a maximal compact subgroup of $G=\mathrm{GL}(V)$ containing $K$, so $L\subset G$ is a homotopy equivalence. If $K$ is a deformation retract of $G$, then $K\subset G$ is a homotopy equivalence, and hence so is $K\subset L$. So $K$ and $L$ have the same number of components, and $K^0\subset L^0$ is a homotopy equivalence; homology in highest degree then says that $K^0$ and $L^0$ have the same dimension and hence $K^0=L^0$, so $K=L$. Since $L$ is conjugate to $\mathrm{O}(V)$, which only preserves, among norms, scalar multiples of the standard one, we conclude.

Comment: The argument is the following. 1. It is is easy to see that $Iso(V)$ is compact. Hence, by averaging we can find a Euclidean metric on $V$ invariant under $Iso(V)$. 2. Now, the unit sphere of the norm is  a convex body in a Euclidean space and $Iso(V)$ is acting by isometries of this convex body (iso with respect to the Euclidean metric). 3. A generic convex body does not have non-trivial isometries